# The name "item" does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, scope

I'm learning c# and I've come across a problem trying to use a foreach loop on a List.  It keeps saying that "item" does not exist.  Here is the code:

```
 static int SumOf(List<int> nums)
    {

        int total = 0;

        List<int> theList = new List<int>(nums);


        theList.ForEach(int item in theList){

            if (item % 2 == 0)
            {
                total += item;
            }

        }
        return total;


    }
```

the foreach method is supposed to iterate through the list and add the even numbers to the total.

Comment: Why do you create a `new` list rather than use the list passed to the method?  See also **[foreach (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in)**

Comment: I've just started with C#.  I was trying anything to make this error go away.  I thought maybe I had to create a new list.  I just tried it without it and it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ForEach` you are using is a `List` method that takes an `Action`.

I think what you want is a `foreach` loop using `foreach` keyword

```
foreach (int item in theList)
{
    if (item % 2 == 0)
    {
        total += item;
    }
}
```

Of course if you want to do it the `ForEach` way then:

```
theList.ForEach((item) =>
    {
        if (item % 2 == 0)
        {
            total += item;
        }
    });
```

The `ForEach` method takes an `Action` that

(Receive an int) => (If it's even, add to total)

and call this `Action` on every element of the list, so the end result should be the same as using a `foreach` loop.

Since you're learning C#, I suppose this article is a good read on Actions.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action?view=netframework-4.8

And here's ForEach's documentation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.foreach?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the extension method ForEach you need to use Action, so you directly have access to the list items as below :

```cs
theList.ForEach(item => total = item % 2 == 0 ? total + item : total);
```

or you can use the `foreach` as below to loop inside the list items:

```cs
foreach(var item in theList) 
{
    if (item % 2 == 0)
    {
        total += item;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the `foreach(type variableName in IEnumerable<T>)` and the `List<T>.ForEach(Action<T>)` is different.
the first one is C# syntax for loop any `IEnumerable<T>` instance (includeing the `List<T>`), the second one is a method of `List<T>`. 
to loop a list ,you can

```
static int SumOf(List<int> nums)
{
    nums = nums ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(nums)); // C# 7 syntax for check the nums is null
    int total = 0;
    foreach(var item in nums)
    {
        total += item;
    }
    return toal;
}
```

Or

```
static int SumOf(List<int> nums)
{
    nums = nums ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(nums)); // C# 7 syntax for check the nums is null
    int total = 0;
    nums.ForEach(item=>total += item;)
    return toal;
}
```

or **use the `Linq` extension method**

```
using System.Linq;

static int SumOf(List<int> nums)
{
    nums = nums ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(nums)); // C# 7 syntax for check the nums is null
    return nums.Sum()
}
```